# Joining two tables together with count

Tags: mysql, left-join

i have two tables named: **orders** and **user_details**

user_details table contains 4 columns: id, name, address, phone..

orders table contains 3 columns: order_id, id, order_date

id is common among the two tables.

Now i want to join these two tables in such a way that i get a table with one column (as name) and another column (as total number of orders).

i tried to use count:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(order_id) FROM orders
LEFT JOIN user_details
ON orders.id = user_details.id;
```

but i know it's wrong...What is the correct approach?

Comment: What is the relationship between user_details and orders ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the group function in order to use the aggregate functions

```
SELECT u.name, COUNT(o.order_id)
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN user_details u
ON o.id = u.id /* make sure you have a correct relation b/w user and order table o.id should point to user id*/
GROUP BY  u.id
```

[**GROUP BY (Aggregate) Functions**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT name, COUNT(order_id) FROM orders
LEFT JOIN user_details
ON orders.id = user_details.id
GROUP BY user_details.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ud.name, count(o.order_id) FROM orders o
JOIN user_details ud
    ON o.id = ud.id
GROUP BY ud.id
```